# Text is disappearing when I try to add an image in PHP + GD library

Tags: php, html, image, gd, imagecreatefrompng

I'm trying to create a PNG with some text and a scaled picture in it. Here is the code for just the text, it works fine:

```
<?php
session_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$label = imagecreate(500, 500);
imagecolorallocate($label, 0, 0, 0);

// up text
$color = imagecolorallocate($label, 255, 255, 255);
imagettftext($label, 50, 0, 0, 150, $color, "arial.ttf", "UP UP UP");

// down text
$color = imagecolorallocate($label, 255, 255, 255);
imagettftext($label, 50, 0, 0, 350, $color, "assets/fonts/arial.ttf", "DOWN DOWN DOWN");

header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($label);
imagedestroy($label);
die();
?>
```

With the code above you get the following picture, which is correct:

[image]

Now I'm trying to have a small picture in it, So I'm loading the picture from a JPEG file (adidas.jpg). Here's the code

```
<?php
session_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL);


$label = imagecreate(500, 500);
imagecolorallocate($label, 0, 0, 0);


// up text
$color = imagecolorallocate($label, 255, 255, 255);
imagettftext($label, 50, 0, 0, 150, $color, "arial.ttf", "UP UP UP");

// image
$src = imagecreatefromjpeg("adidas.jpg");
$pic = imagecreatetruecolor(500, 500);
imagecopyresampled($label, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, 150, 150, imagesx($src), imagesy($src));
$white = imagecolorallocate($pic, 255, 255, 255);
imagefill($label,0,0,$white);
imagedestroy($pic);


// down text
$color = imagecolorallocate($label, 255, 255, 255);
imagettftext($label, 50, 0, 0, 350, $color, "arial.ttf", "DOWN DOWN DOWN");

header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($label);
imagedestroy($label);
die();
?>
```

And this is what I get:

[image]

To my surprise the "down" text disappeared. Why is that? The text added *before the picture* is fine, the text added *after it* turns to black for some reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is bit messy, "DOWN.." text will appear if you remove second:

```
$color = imagecolorallocate($label, 255, 255, 255);
```

You dont fill the original image, you try it later but with wrong color ($white is from $pic, not $label).
I cleaned it up:

```
<?php
session_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$label = imagecreate(500, 500);
$black = imagecolorallocate($label, 0, 0, 0);
$white = imagecolorallocate($label, 255, 255, 255);
imagefill($label, 0, 0, $black);

imagettftext($label, 50, 0, 0, 150, $white, "arial.ttf", "UP UP UP");

$src = imagecreatefromjpeg("adidas.jpg");
$pic = imagecreatetruecolor(500, 500);
imagecopyresampled($label, $src, 0, 0, 0, 0, 150, 150, imagesx($src), imagesy($src));
$white2 = imagecolorallocate($pic, 255, 255, 255);

imagettftext($label, 50, 0, 0, 350, $white, "arial.ttf", "DOWN DOWN DOWN");

ob_end_clean();
header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($label);

imagedestroy($src);
imagedestroy($pic);
imagedestroy($label);
die();
?>
```

Comment: using your code both text ("up" and "down") disappeared. Please try

Comment: if both texts are gone then check font path.

Comment: you're right, font path was wrong, now it works, I see both texts